# How to add property to ruby variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create variable `item`
And write something like this:

`item.property1 = "whatever"
item.poperty2 = "whatever"`

How do I do this?

Right now I am doing it like this:
`item = {}
item [:property1] = "whatever"`

Any other options?

Comment: I suggest you read [some basic tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the simplest solutions I know of:

If you know the attributes in advance, then use a Struct:

```
Item = Struct.new(:property1, :property2)
item = Item.new('blue', 'medium')  # or:
item = Item.new
item.property1 = 'blue'
item.property2 = 'medium'

puts item.property1
puts item.property2
```

Otherwise, you can use an OpenStruct:

```
require 'ostruct'
item = OpenStruct.new
item.property1 = 'blue'
item.property2 = 'medium'

puts item.property1
puts item.property2
```

Comment: OpenStruct is great for this.

Comment: Just so you know, I removed a line from this script that was incorrect: `item = OpenStruct.new('blue', 'medium')  # or:`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object to access variables like that.

```
class Item 
   attr_accessor :property1, :property2
end
```

Then you could do what you wrote:

```
item = Item.new
item.property1 = "whatever"
item.poperty2 = "whatever"
```

If you are talking about a Rails database object there is more to it though (like writing a database migration first).